# AND selector jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use an AND selector in jQuery? I am trying to filter through results where I need multiple selectors to be true. This is what I use but instead of "OR" so the "," I use I want to use "AND".

```
$('div.job:not([data-province="'+province+'"])', 'div.job:not([data-employment="'+employment+'"])', 'div.job:not([data-education="'+education+'"])', 'div.job:not([data-branch="'+branch+'"])').fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: Are you trying to find elements with all of those data-* tags? If so you can stick all those :not() selectors one after the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do that, you are actually looking for `combined attribute selector`.

Try,

```
$('div.job[data-province!="'+province+'"][data-employment!="'+employment+'"][data-education!="'+education+'"][data-branch!="'+branch+'"]').fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir Why.? curious to know the reason.?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I am confused at this point. Why did my selector not work.? Can you explain.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy You missed to quote so it's not working :not([]) should be :not('[]')

Comment: **the answer is DEMORGAN**. the `not(a+b+c) = not(a)*not(b)*not(c)`. your second solution with the filter represents the right side of the equation. which is correct. but your first solution stated : `not(a*b*c)` whic is incorrect.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Thanks you pointing the issue.! i just managed to write a solution with out a not selector. See the update. Thanks.!

Comment: I am not getting the results I need. When I for example enter the values 6, 5, 3, 1 there should be 1 result that shouldn't fade. But instead none of them fade out so it doesn't do anything. I don't get errors either. I did check the values with console.log() just in case but they are correct.

Comment: @SinanSamet Make a working demo of that, so that we can fix it easily.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qomub/11/edit?html,js,output I made that I hope I did it right. But that should be only displaying Test 1. And fade out Test 2 and 3

Comment: It seems to work! But I want the ones who are correct to fadeIn and I did this for that but I get an error. http://jsbin.com/qomub/14/edit

Comment: Oh I just had to remove the brackets it works now thanks! One last thing. How would I add an or to it? For example I want the ones which are not equal to 1 OR nothing ""

Comment: @SinanSamet Hey that's a nice question. Just post that as a new one. so that you would get more expert attention over that. :)

Comment: Alright thank you. Thought I shouldn't do that because people would maybe give me negative points for going on about the same question.