# Using OR condition in combined attribute selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I asked this question earlier and got it solved:
[AND selector jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722496/and-selector-jquery/21722567)

But now I would like to know how I could add an OR condition to it.

I have this statement:

```
$('div.job:not([data-province="'+province+'"][data-employment="'+employment+'"][data-education="'+education+'"][data-branch="'+branch+'"])').fadeOut('slow');
```

And now I would like to fade them out if for example data-province="'+province+'" OR data-province="" (so empty).

Jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/qomub/14/edit

Comment: you should use `.filter()` to keep your selector more readable

Comment: It's only me that couldn't understand your question with and/or in both question!

Comment: the jsbin sample seems to be working fine what is the probelm

Comment: Can you post your html so we can see the select elements and their values, and then explain (in the question above) what the actual problem is.  You're asking for a solution to your interpretation of the issue, rather than the actual issue itself.

Comment: I will try to make a more complete jsbin

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yG9Zv/1/ that's what I got. And I want the filters to work also when nothing is selected on other filters (selects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('div.job').filter('[data-province="' + province + '"], [data-province=""]').fadeOut('slow');
```

---

Based on the update

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $jobs = $('.job');
    var $selects = $("#province, #employment, #education, #branch").on("change", function () {
        var $filtered = $jobs;

        $selects.each(function () {
            if (this.value) {
                $filtered = $filtered.filter('[data-' + this.id + '="' + this.value + '"], [data-' + this.id + '=""]');
            }
        });
        $filtered.show();
        $jobs.not($filtered).hide();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D4Fmh/1/)

Comment: Would I just make div.job:not from it to get the ones who are not true to the statement?

Comment: @SinanSamet filter() accepts any kind of valid selector, you can add `:not()` statement inside filter

Comment: @downvoter, what is wrong with this answer? It gives the general idea

Comment: It gives me this error when I add the :not statement. Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: not:([data-province="6"][data-employment=""][data-education=""][data-branch=""])

Comment: @SinanSamet your syntax is wrong try `:not([data-province="6"][data-employment=""][data-education=""][data-branch=""])`

Comment: $('div.job').filter(':not([data-province="'+province+'"], [data-province=""][data-employment="'+employment+'"], [data-employment=""][data-education="'+education+'"], [data-education=""][data-branch="'+branch+'"]‌​, [data-branch=""])').fadeOut('slow');
Thats what I have but they don't disappear. If it is not so clear I will try to make a demo in jsbin.

Comment: @SinanSamet what are you trying to do? if you can tell that then we can have a look

Comment: Well I have 4 select fields with ids as values in the options. The data attributes that do not match with the ids or should disappear. The ones who do match or are empty should not disappear. In my code province is var province = $("#province").val(); and #province is the select field.

Comment: I made this jsfiddle and it works exactly like it does on mine. I hope it makes it more clear: http://jsfiddle.net/yG9Zv/1/

Comment: Wow you are awesome! Besides that it works like a charm, the code is so much shorter! Thanks a lot I will study the code so I can learn from it!

Comment: @SinanSamet the main problem in your question was the context of the problem... you were trying to solve a tiny portion of the problem without giving us the entire context.... once I had it, it was a less than 5 mins job to solve it